# ¿Por qué Appbundle en Play Console tarda mucho en revisión sin que la rechacen o se comuniquen?

Tags: android, flutter, console, store, play

**La revisión lleva poco más de 7 días**, esta fue una actualización fuerte pues se pasó el `sdktarget` de 30 a 33 y el `flutter` de 1.22.2 a 3.3 (según el `puspec.lock`) pero sin el `sound null safety`, por tanto, se tuvieron que migrar muchos paquetes, **pero siento que ya va mucho tiempo**. La última actualización fue en julio del año pasado, se intentó obtener soporte de `Play Console` pero los métodos son muy limitados hasta donde se investigó, se intentó meter otra versión dos días después que la primera pensándolo como solución, pero ahora ambas versiones están en revisión. `Play Console` no se ha comunicado por correo ni por algún otro medio; se tiene instalada la app de `Play Console` y tampoco por ese medio hay avisos. **La app ya está en producción desde hace ya casi 3 años.**

Answer (score 2):

La revisión actualmente puede durar algunas horas, una semana, o incluso más, hace algunos años podía durar solo unas horas.

Esto lo que indica **Google Play Console** actualmente para una publicación estandar:

> **De forma predeterminada, su aplicación utilizará la publicación
> estándar. Ciertas aplicaciones pueden estar sujetas a revisiones
> extendidas, lo que puede resultar en tiempos de revisión de hasta 7
> días o más en casos excepcionales.**

**Debes tomar en cuenta que ahora la revisión también se realiza con base en la información que defines en los cuestionarios acerca del contenido de la app**, así que revisa que todos se encuentren realizados y que la información en los mismos sea la correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ocasiones puede quedar pendiente como "Draft" tu aplicación, así que te sugiero revises el proceso de liberación que no tiene algo pendiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La aplicación se publico después de 12 días, no me había sucedido que tardara ese tiempo cuando la aplicación ya esta en producción, espero que ayude a alguien mas a saber que suele tardar así cuando hay muchos cambios en la versión como también que ha pasado mucho tiempo desde que se actualizo por ultima ves